# Undefined symbols of library1 and library2 are the same

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to use the same like this:

> Undefined symbols of library1 and library2 are the same.

I mean that both libraries have the same undefined symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: Is it correct to use "the same" like this?

Answer: Yes, that's fine.

This sentence is somewhat terse. (although that may fit the context...)

> Undefined symbols of library1 and library2 are the same.

Other options:

> The undefined symbols in library1 and library2 are the same.
>   The undefined symbols of library1 and library2 are the same.
>   Both libraries have the same undefined symbols.